# Phaser 3 - Duplicate Canvas component is created when creating a new instance of Phaser 3 GameObject in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I'm using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) as framework and trying to render the GameObject `new Phaser.Game(gameConfig)` as React component. I am able to render but it creates a duplicate Canvas object as shown below:
[image]

Here is my Game Component:

```
import Phaser from "phaser";
import React from "react";

export default class Game extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const gameConfig: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            parent: 'game-container',
            backgroundColor: '#EBEBEB',
            width: 600,
            height: 800
        }

        new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return <div id='game-container' />   
    }
}
```

And here is where I'm rendering:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Game from './game';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Game />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

How do I remove this duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem could be, that due to the `<React.StrictMode>` Tag, that the function `componentDidMount`, might be executed twice. If you remove this tag, the function will not be execute twice.
And since each call of `componentDidMount` creates a new phaser *gameobject*, due to the `new Phaser.Game(...)` call. Which in turn creates a new canvas.

Since the Tag `<React.StrictMode>` is not really needed for production, you can remove it without problems/changes to your UI output.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
    class Game extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            const gameConfig = {
                type: Phaser.AUTO,
                parent: 'game-container',
                backgroundColor: '#EBEBEB',
                width: 300,
                height: 120,
                scene: {create(){ this.add.text(150,60, 'GAME').setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize(80).setOrigin(.5).setColor('#000000')}}
            }

            new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
        }

        shouldComponentUpdate() {
            return false;
        }

        render() {
            return <div id='game-container' /> 
        }
    }

    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    // creates two canvas elements
    root.render( <React.StrictMode><Game /></React.StrictMode> );
    // creates one canvas elements
    root.render( <Game /> );
</script>
```